# Tailwind does not let me use some attributes while using NextUI + React

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, nextui

I am working on a React project with NextUI + Tailwind but I have got some styling problems.

If i want to use some attributes e.g. a bigger padding, margin or even a bg-color like:

```
<div className='flex bg-indigo-500 px-10'>
```

It will just not work. Tailwind does not change anything. I have tried with different paddings and sometimes it is limited at 6, sometimes at 4. Some background colors work, some does not. If I take a plain CSS file and create a class with the `margin-bottom: 50px;` or `background-color: pink;` and write it additionally to the className mentioned above, then it is going to work.

```
<div className='flex bg-indigo-500 px-10' class="testMargin">
```

Is it possible that Tailwind somehow interferes with the built in NextUI elements, or some attributes are limited automatically in the `tailwind.config.js`?

I have tried searching for similar problems, but did not find anything useful. I have also restarted the project from zero, and reinstalled all the packages, but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: *Please update the above question by adding your `tailwind.config.js` code.*